# Unable to click a link residing inside a <li element

Tags: html, css, dom, protractor

I am not able to click on the link nestled inside a list tag.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="sideBarContent" ng-include="'routes/sidebar/sidebar.tpl.html'">
<div id="innerSidebarContent" ng-controller="SidebarController">
<div>
<ul class="menuItems bounceInDown">
<li id="menuHome" class="" ui-sref="home" ng-click="closeMobileMenu()" href="/home/">
<li id="menuConfigurator" ui-sref="configurator" ng-click="closeMobileMenu()" href="/configurator/">
<span class="menuIcon regularImage blueHighlight activated icon-selectAndTailor"></span>
<span class="menuIcon icon-selectAndTailor_active activeImage">
<p class="mainMenuLabel multiLine">Select & Tailor Methods</p>
</li>
```

I tried all these ways to locate the text and click on it:

```
describe('Test objects in /configurator/ route', function() {
it('Click on select and tailor banner icon', function(){
    //element(by.css('ul.menuItems > li[href=/configurator/]')).click();
    //element(by.className('menuIcon icon-selectAndTailor_active activeImage')).click();
    //element(by.css("li[@id='menuConfigurator' and @href='/configurator/']")).click();
    //element(by.id('menuConfigurator')).click();
    //element(by.xpath("//div[@class='sideBarContent']/p")).click();
    //element(by.css("#menuConfigurator > p")).click();
    //element(by.partialLinkText('Select & Tailor Methods')).click();
    element(by.linkText("Select & Tailor Methods")).click();
    console.log('in the configspec ...');
})});
```

Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: `li` cannot `href` attribute. You should instead of `a` tag inside `li` and have `href` to `a` tag.

Comment: use `element(by.cssConatiningText("li","Select & Tailor Methods")).click();`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj, thanks, the cssContainingText syntax worked, finally!

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue.
It turned out that wrapping the list in a < div > block was the problem.
Once the list was moved to be outside any < div > block the < a > tags worked.

Comment: I put ul in div tag and div-ul-li-a is working

Answer (score 0):

li can not have href attribute

Use

```
<a href="/home"><li id="menuHome" class="" ui-sref="home" ng-click="closeMobileMenu()"></a></li>
```

Or

```
<li id="menuHome" class="" ui-sref="home" ng-click="closeMobileMenu()" href="/home/"><a href="/home"></a></li>
```

Instead of

```
<li id="menuHome" class="" ui-sref="home" ng-click="closeMobileMenu()" href="/home/"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to html this is not link. 
Select it using other selectors:

```
element(by.className("multiLine")).click();

element(by.css(".mainMenuLabel.multiLine")).click();

element(by.css("[class='mainMenuLabel multiLine']")).click();

element(by.xpath(".//p[@class='mainMenuLabel multiLine']")).click();
```

Comment: I cannot use class='mainMenuLabel multiLine' because there are numerous elements with that class name inside a <p tag.